# Nuxt3 with vue-plyr for YouTube - Document is not defined Reference Error

Tags: vue.js, youtube, vuejs3, nuxtjs3, vue-plyr

I'm trying to implement the **[vue-plyr](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@skjnldsv/vue-plyr)** with a new **Nuxt3** application, so that I can embed customized YouTube and Vimeo videos into the pages.

I have followed the instructions for Nuxt (Vue 2.x) at the bottom of the vue-plyr npm page to use the component in Nuxt, by creating a file in the **plugins** directory and wrapping the component in a `<ClientOnly>` tag, but I am still getting an error.

`/plugins/vue-plyr.ts`

```js
import VuePlyr from 'vue-plyr/dist/vue-plyr.ssr'
import 'vue-plyr/dist/vue-plyr.css'

export default defineNuxtPlugin((nuxtApp) => {
  nuxtApp.vueApp.use(VuePlyr, { plyr: {} })
})
```

`nuxt.config.ts`

```js
import { defineNuxtConfig } from 'nuxt'

// https://v3.nuxtjs.org/api/configuration/nuxt.config
export default defineNuxtConfig({
    plugins: [
        { src: '~/plugins/vue-plyr', mode: 'client' }
    ]
})
```

`app.vue`

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <!-- <NuxtWelcome /> -->
    <div>
        Video
        <ClientOnly>
          <vue-plyr>
            <div class="plyr__video-embed">
              <iframe
                src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/bTqVqk7FSmY?amp;iv_load_policy=3&amp;modestbranding=1&amp;playsinline=1&amp;showinfo=0&amp;rel=0&amp;enablejsapi=1"
                allowfullscreen
                allowtransparency
                allow="autoplay"
              ></iframe>
            </div>
          </vue-plyr>
        </ClientOnly>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">

</script>
```

**Error**

```
ReferenceError: document is not defined
    at C:\Users\benm\Documents\Coding\My Projects\yt-test\node_modules\vue-plyr\dist\vue-plyr.ssr.js:5913:11
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\benm\Documents\Coding\My Projects\yt-test\node_modules\vue-plyr\dist\vue-plyr.ssr.js:5924:2)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1063:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1092:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:928:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:769:14)
    at ModuleWrap.<anonymous> (internal/modules/esm/translators.js:199:29)
    at ModuleJob.run (internal/modules/esm/module_job.js:152:23)
    at async Loader.import (internal/modules/esm/loader.js:166:24)
    at async __instantiateModule__ (file:///C:/Users/benm/Documents/Coding/My%20Projects/yt-test/.nuxt/dist/server/server.mjs:4156:3)
```

Comment: @kissu I looked at those answers, but none of them worked for me. I am still getting the same error. I don't import the component extra in the page so the answer you linked doesn't work here. Perhaps because I'm using vuejs3 and nuxt3...

Answer (score 3):

i found a way to get it working

so in your plugin folder create a file called
`plyr.client.ts` its al about the `.client.ts`

add this as its contents

```
const VuePlayer = VuePlyr;

export default defineNuxtPlugin((nuxtApp) => {
  nuxtApp.vueApp.use(VuePlayer, { plyr: {} });
});
```

in `nuxt.config.ts` add

`css: ["@/assets/css/main.scss", "~/node_modules/vue-plyr/dist/vue-plyr.css"],`

so here you add the css of the node module and then you can use this in your pages/component

````
        <vue-plyr>
          <div class="plyr__video-embed">
            <iframe
              src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/bTqVqk7FSmY?amp;iv_load_policy=3&amp;modestbranding=1&amp;playsinline=1&amp;showinfo=0&amp;rel=0&amp;enablejsapi=1"
              allowfullscreen
              allowtransparency
              allow="autoplay"
            ></iframe>
          </div>
        </vue-plyr>
      </ClientOnly>```
````

Comment: It's always important to use such a thing like videoPlayer on client, never during SSR. that's why using plugin suffixed client works, good job

Comment: Just for the shake of completeness, for the plugin, you need to import VuePlyr like this `import VuePlyr from '@skjnldsv/vue-plyr/dist/index.js'`